# Documentar funciones y constructores sobrecargados

Tags: jsdoc

Tengo el siguiente constructor de clase:

```
class Logger {
  /** @constructs
      @param { number } minlevel Minimal level to shown log
      @param { function } callback to really do the process
  */
  constructor( minlevel, callback ) {
    if( minlevel instanceof Logger ) {
      // Duplicar el objeto.
      this.$callback = minlevel.$callback;

      if( typeof( callback ) === 'number' ) {
        this.$minLevel = callback;
      } else {
        this.$minLevel = minlevel.$minLevel;
      }
    } else {
      // Nueva instancia.
      if( typeof( callback ) != 'function' ) throw TypeError( );

      this.$minLevel = minlevel;
      this.$callback = callback;
    }
  }
}
```

Este constructor posee 2 *sobrecargas* (casos de uso, con distintos tipos de argumentos y distinto resultado). Expresado en TypeScript (para clarificar), seria así:

- `constructor( other : Logger, minlevel? : number )`

  Usado para *clonar* una instancia; genera una copia, con un argumento `minlevel` opcional.
- `constructor( minlevel : number, callback : Function )`

  Usado para crear una nueva instancia sin depender de ninguna otra.

Me gustaría documentar **ambas sobrecargas** usando *JSDoc*, pero no encuentro la forma correcta. Tal y como está ahora, genera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que es lo que espero para **la segunda sobrecarga**.

¿ Como puedo documentar funciones/constructores/*getters*/*setters* *sobrecargados* usando JSDoc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente, encontré la solución (en inglés): [How Do I Document an Overloaded Constructor](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1017)

En ese enlace, se indica *literalmente*

> You need to nestle the start and end of each comment

Sin embargo, creo mas adecuado indicar que las descripciones de las distintas sobrecargas **han de colocarse inmediatamente consecutivos unas de otras**:

```
class Logger {
  /**
    @constructs
    @param { number } minlevel Minimal level to shown logs
    @param { function } callback to really do the process
  *//**
    @constructs
    @param { Logger } instance Instance to copy
    @param { number } minlevel Minimal level to shown logs
  */
  constructor( minlevel, callback ) {
    if( minlevel instanceof Logger ) {
      // Duplicar el objeto.
      this.$callback = minlevel.$callback;

      if( typeof( callback ) === 'number' ) {
        this.$minLevel = callback;
      } else {
        this.$minLevel = minlevel.$minLevel;
      }
    } else {
      // Nueva instancia.
      if( typeof( callback ) != 'function' ) throw TypeError( );

      this.$minLevel = minlevel;
      this.$callback = callback;
    }
  }
}
```

El resultado obtenido, ahora si, es satisfactorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]